# How to forget/remove Mobile Broadband connection settings from Mint 14

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, 3g

I've been using Ubuntu for a while now and wanted to switch to Mint. I connected my mobile broadband dongle (Vodafone) for the first time like in Ubuntu it all went fine but subsequent connections were denied. I tried connecting with other network dongles and they could connect me to the Internet. My main dongle with the most stable internet connection is Vodafone.

How can I remove or forget the setting and do it as fresh again?

If anyone has better options as well, I am willing to try it.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete related profile file under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` for LinuxMint.

More info: https://superuser.com/questions/517678/how-can-i-reset-all-network-settings-in-linux-mint

Answer (score 0):

to remove connections 1st go to activities/show application/sundry/network connection.then you see the connections which are used before & you can edit or delete unwanted connections.